# Cannot resolve method 'getBody' in Message

Tags: java, jms, mom

I’m quite new in JavaEE and trying to deal with JMS stuff. Here is the **MessageBean** that implement *MessageListener* and Override **onMessage** where I consequently try to receive message from Queue
My code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
 try{
  System.out.println(message.getBody(String.class));
 }catch(JMSException e){
   System.err.println(e.toString());
 }
}
```

But unfortunately there is an compiling error that method **getBody cannot be resolved** and marked as red in IntelliJ. Help me figure out. Thanks in advance

Comment: What package of Message?

Comment: @ToànNguyễnHải onMessage is method from interface MessageListener. But Object that sends message is JMSProducer which is from java.jms package

Comment: share your pom.xml. I prefer you should read the tutorial of spring-jms https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-jms first

Comment: @ToànNguyễnHải I don’t use Spring I use EJB and MessageBean... I’ve just started studying EE and try to figure out how to work with EJB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`getBody(Class<T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getBody-java.lang.Class-) is new in JMS 2.0. Your project is almost certainly including the JMS 1.1 specification jar. Change your project so you include the JMS 2.0 specification jar instead and that error should go away.